# c ++ vector as thread-specific data

Tags: c++, multithreading

the raw function is like:

```
void func(int N, double R){
  vector<double> x;
  vector<double> y;
  #x.push_back(sth)y.push_back(sth) according to N
  #do some calculation using x and y. result is stored in R
}
```

now I want it to work in multi-thread. the vector x and y is independent in each thread, means they are thread private data. 
I googled and found I should use **pthread_key_create**. I read some examples but still got no idea how to do it. In all examples the thread data are  strings or int object. I simply replace them with vector but it doesn't work.
---------------------------------------------my code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "errors.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
typedef struct Points{
    std::vector<int> X;
    std::vector<int> Y;
}Points;

pthread_key_t key;
pthread_once_t once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

void once_routine(void)
{
    int status;
    printf("Initializing key\n");
    status = pthread_key_create(&key, NULL);
    if(status != 0){
            err_abort(status, "pthread_key_create");
    }
}

void *thread_routine( void *arg)
{
    int status;
    Points *value = NULL;

    status = pthread_once(&once, once_routine);
    if(status != 0){
            err_abort(status, "pthread_once");
    }

    value = (Points *)malloc(sizeof(Points));
    if(value == NULL){
            errno_abort("malloc");
    }

    status = pthread_setspecific(key, (void *)value);
    if(status != 0){
            err_abort(status, "pthread_setspecific");
    }

    value->X.push_back(*(int *)arg);
    value->Y.push_back(*(int *)arg);

    sleep(2);
    value = (Points *)pthread_getspecific(key);
    if(value == NULL){
            printf("no thread-specific data value was associated \
                    with key\n");
            pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    printf("%d done......\n", pthread_self());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int status;
    int * pp1 = NULL;
    *pp1 = 111;
    status = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_routine, pp1);
    if(status != 0){
            err_abort(status, "create thread1");
    }
    int * pp2 = NULL;
    *pp2 = 222;
    status = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread_routine, pp2);
    if(status != 0){
            err_abort(status, "create thread2");
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

---

**thank you all guys. I usually use python. this time the code on python works slowly so I thought maybe I should try c++. Now I realized this is not a good idea since I havent wrote c++  for a long time**

Comment: That ==> `(Points *)malloc(sizeof(Points));` is your first problem. This isn't C, and that has no business being in this program. That ==> `int * pp1 = NULL; *pp1 = 111;` is your second problem, and is invoking **undefined behavior**, likewise with `int * pp2 = NULL; *pp2 = 222`. Not realizing *either* are problems, yet trying to code a pthread multi-threaded application in C++, is easily your biggest problem.

Comment: Note that the function you posted at the top of your question does not have to be changed at all in order to work in multiple threads.

Comment: thank you all guys. I usually use python. this time the code on python works slowly so I thought maybe I should try c++. Now I realized this is not a good idea since I havent write c++ code for a long time